# Cruising to Vietnam

Tags: visas, vietnam, cruising

I am a US citizen. In November, I will be taking a cruise, which will have multiple stops at Vietnam ports. I have researched a lot on visas and it looks like I need a multiple-entry visa. Can someone confirm this and how does one obtain one? I really don't want to do Visa on Arrival (VoA) since it appears to be time-consuming. Also I will not be entering at any airport. The cruise is less than 2 weeks long. The cruise ship will not do it for us but did give us some names of visa companies.

Comment: You can apply for a visa yourself [here](https://vietnamvisa.govt.vn).

Answer (score 4):

If you are a [US citizen traveling to Vietnam](https://vn.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-traveling-vietnam/) you can obtain a visa by any of the following 3 methods:

1. You can apply ahead of time at a Vietnamese embassy. (Recommended)
2. You can apply for an [e-visa](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/). However, the online service is for
   single entry only.
3. You can get a visa on arrival though it seems you need a pre-approval
   for it which may cost more as it involves travel agencies.

The easiest for you would be to apply for a 1 month multiple entry visa at the [Embassy in DC](http://vietnamembassy-usa.org/content/visa-application-process) using any of the below methods.

You can apply in person if you can go all the way to DC. It's a walk-in process and no appointments are needed.  Otherwise, you can apply by [mail](http://visa.vietnamembassy-usa.org/) or by [email](http://vietnamembassy-usa.org/page/apply-email-and-receive-loose-leaf-visa-mail); the processing time is 3 business days and you will get the visa via mail.

Comment: This answers how to get one, but it doesn't answer if it is necessary.

Comment: I thought it was a default understanding since the OP knows that it is required. And if you follow the first link it leads to a more information (travel.state.gov) that a visa is required. Even for the on-arrival visa, you need a preapproval as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Well given that the actual *question* in the OP's post was "[c]an someone confirm this and how does one obtain one?" (where "this" referring to the multi-entry requirement), not really.